# One build\release for all environments vs multiple biulds\releases for all environments

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, release, pipeline

At my current setup this is what's happening,

- Build Dev
- Build Uat
- Build Production

and then,

- Release Dev
- Release Uat
- Release Production

Now the problem is that we only have 1 agent (not sure why), it doesn't happens often but sometimes we need to build and release hot fixes quickly however each BUILD takes around 10+ minutes and can't run in parallel to other builds. Same for releases. So, for deploying a hotfix to production just takes painful process of 2 hours or so.

**Need for seperate builds:**

- While building we are specifying the build command like this,

  ng build -configuration --uat

  ng build -configuration --prod

Why we shouldn't create One build\release for all environments ? Assuming there will work arounds to create different artifacts for different configurations or we may just use application settings on azure or soemthing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question leans towards getting primarily opinion based answers ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)), I *am* going to go ahead with answering it.

As far as I'm concerned, you *should* have only one build and have the artifacts travel across all* environments. The binaries (artifacts) do not change, only their configuration does. This is the only way you can **make sure** that there **aren't any differences** between code running on different environments.

* Your Development environment might/can be a special cookie. Some Dev environments enable developers to do remote debugging and that kind of tasks, so having a Debug build on your Dev environment makes sense.